# Contact Form 7 not working on Internet Explorer

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer, contact-form-7

I am checking my websites Browser Compatibility and I found that on Submit, my form won't submit, It stuck on loading. If someone could please assist with this situation, I would appreciate it. I am a beginner, so not sure what to do.

I thought it might be the JS loading, so in the plugins editor, I changed the

```
define( ‘WPCF7_LOAD_JS’, true);
```

to

```
define( ‘WPCF7_LOAD_JS’, false);
```

This still did not fix my issue.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: could you try deactivating all other plugins?

Comment: I am worried that if I deactivate, I might loose all my settings and content. This site is live....

Comment: you can take backup of your db  and then deactivate plugins so if data won't restored after activating them you can replace the db to get your settings back.  usually settings will restored after the plugin in reactivated.

Comment: Okay, I found the issue, it is with a pop up plugin I had. Which means I need to either replace that plugin or something, because I used it everywhere on my site

Comment: yes, or if it just simpaly generating popup like subscribe to news letter you can put that manually too.

Comment: If you show the picture of your popup than we can try to suggest an example for that. In general, You can try to refer link below for creating form popup. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_popup_form.asp